# Swift 4: Two UITableView in one UIViewController, scroll function not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I have two UITableView in one UIViewController and feeding those tables with data from Rest API. it all seems works fine but then I realize that the scrolling is not working. I have other UITableViewController with scrolling working just fine.

here is the code of my ViewController

here is the class

```
class DashboardController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

   var lowerTableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.isScrollEnabled = true
    tv.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
    return tv
}()

 var upperTableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.isScrollEnabled = true
    tv.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    return tv
}()
```

...
viewDidLoad() function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if user?.status != "success" {
        handleLogout()
    } else {

        self.navigationItem.title = "Dashboard"
        self.userName.text = user?.fullname

        upperTableView.dataSource = self
        upperTableView.delegate = self

        lowerTableView.dataSource = self
        lowerTableView.delegate = self

        handleRefresh()

        upperTableView.register(QuizCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        lowerTableView.register(QuizCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")

        setupNavBarButtons()
        setupDashboard()

    }
}
```

...
and numberOfRowsInSection method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count:Int?

    if tableView == self.upperTableView {
        count = sampleData.count
        // count = 10
    }

    if tableView == self.lowerTableView {
        count =  closedQuizList.count
        // count = 10
    }

    return count!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell?

    if tableView == self.upperTableView {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let datum = sampleData[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = datum.name
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = datum.quiz_type+" - "+datum.start_date!+" - "+datum.end_date!
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.textColor = .blue
    }

    if tableView == self.lowerTableView {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
        let datum = closedQuizList[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = datum.name + " (" + datum.score! + ")"


    }
    return cell!
}
```

here is setupDashboard() code

```
func setupDashboard() {

    let upperDashboard = UIView()
    upperDashboard.backgroundColor = .white

    let lowerDashboard = UIView()
    lowerDashboard.backgroundColor = .white

    let dashboardStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [upperDashboard, lowerDashboard])
    dashboardStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dashboardStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    dashboardStackView.axis = .vertical

    view.addSubview(dashboardStackView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        dashboardStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        dashboardStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        dashboardStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        dashboardStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        ])


    // upperDashboard part
    upperDashboard.addSubview(userName)
    upperDashboard.addSubview(userStatus)
    upperDashboard.addSubview(upperLabel)
    upperDashboard.addSubview(upperLabelSeparator)
    upperDashboard.addSubview(statsButton)
    upperDashboard.addSubview(upperTableView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        // userName
        userName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperDashboard.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        userName.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperDashboard.leftAnchor, constant: 12),
        userName.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperDashboard.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
        // userStatus
        userStatus.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperDashboard.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        userStatus.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperDashboard.rightAnchor, constant: -12),
        userStatus.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperDashboard.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
        // upperLabel
        statsButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userName.bottomAnchor, constant: 6),
        statsButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperDashboard.leftAnchor, constant: 12),
        statsButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperDashboard.widthAnchor, constant: -24),
        statsButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        // statsButton
        upperLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statsButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 6),
        upperLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statsButton.leadingAnchor),
        upperLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statsButton.widthAnchor),
        // upperLabelSeparator
        upperLabelSeparator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperLabel.bottomAnchor),
        upperLabelSeparator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperLabel.leadingAnchor),
        upperLabelSeparator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperLabel.widthAnchor),
        upperLabelSeparator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 4),
        // upperTableView
        upperTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperLabelSeparator.bottomAnchor),
        upperTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerDashboard.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
        upperTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerDashboard.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
        upperTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerDashboard.bottomAnchor)
        ])

    // lowerDashboard part
    lowerDashboard.addSubview(lowerLabel)
    lowerDashboard.addSubview(lowerLabelSeparator)
    lowerDashboard.addSubview(lowerTableView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        // lowerLabel
        lowerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerDashboard.topAnchor),
        lowerLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerDashboard.leftAnchor, constant: 12),
        lowerLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerDashboard.widthAnchor, constant: -24),
        // lowerLabelSeparator
        lowerLabelSeparator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerLabel.bottomAnchor),
        lowerLabelSeparator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerLabel.leadingAnchor),
        lowerLabelSeparator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerLabel.widthAnchor),
        lowerLabelSeparator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 4),
        // lowerTableView
        lowerTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerLabelSeparator.bottomAnchor),
        lowerTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerDashboard.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
        lowerTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerDashboard.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
        lowerTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerDashboard.bottomAnchor)
        ])

}
```

Comment: I have never seen a UI that benefits from having multiple `UITableView`s on a single screen. `UITableView` and `IndexPath` support grouping up your content into sections while still using one table view. Your comment that "scrolling is not working" is too vague to pinpoint, but if you mean that scrolling one table view does not affect the other, then yes, that is intended behavior.

Comment: well, what should I have said to describe better? the tableView is not scrollable. it didn't scroll at all when I try to scroll down the tableView.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class DashboardController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

lazy var lowerTableView: UITableView = {
  let tv = UITableView()
  tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  tv.isScrollEnabled = true
  tv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  tv.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
  return tv
}()

lazy var upperTableView: UITableView = {
  let tv = UITableView()
  tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  tv.isScrollEnabled = true
  tv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  tv.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
  return tv
}()
```

This way you don't have to set the delegate and dataSource inside of viewDidLoad.
I also would not call tableview.`register` again inside viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  if user?.status != "success" {
      handleLogout()
  } else {

    self.navigationItem.title = "Dashboard"
    self.userName.text = user?.fullname

    self.view.addSubView(lowerTableView)
    self.view.addSUbView(upperTableView)

    handleRefresh()

    setupNavBarButtons()
    setupDashboard()

    }
}
```

If this doesn't work can you show me what `setupDashboard()` does?

Comment: this doesn't work, I updated the question with setupDashboard() code. thanks for the help

Comment: I can’t figure out why it’s not working. Are you sure the dataSource for the tables has more items than the amount of items already showing on screen? Getting any errors for ambiguous or unsatisfiable constraints?

Comment: I just realize that the lowerTableView scroll is working fine. it is only upperTableView scrolling that is not working

Comment: Try debugging the view hierarchy. You will be able to see if there is anything on top of the table that it’s preventing it from scrolling. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Comment: thanks for the advice @Chamanhm ! it's really helpful. my fault was on this line `upperTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerDashboard.bottomAnchor)` it should be `lowerDashboard.topAnchor`, so it's actually not scrolling problem but the first tableView extend behind the second tableView. silly me.